# Matrix of a Linear Transformation with respect to the bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The question goes as follows:

Let $L :\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$
$$
                     L(x,y) = (y,x+y,x-y)$$
Find the matrix associated to $L$ with respect to the bases $B = (u_1,u_2)$ of $\mathbb R^2$ and $D = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of $\mathbb R^3$, where:
$$\begin{align*}
                   u_1 &= (1,2)\\    u_2 &= (3,1)\\
                   v_1 &= (1,0,0)\\  v_2 &= (1,1,0)\\  v_3 &= (1,1,1)
\end{align*}$$
I couldn't find anything on the internet that where it showed how to calculate the matrix when the vector space changed from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$. In all the solution videos, the vector spaces always stayed the same.

I have an exam in 2 days and I am desperate for any help.

(Also I apologise for the formatting, I looked up on the internet how to enter symbols such as real numbers but it didn't seem to work.)

Comment: Hi :) First, compute $a_{1, 1},a_{2,1},a_{3,1}$ such that $L(u_1)=a_{1, 1}v_1+a_{2, 1}v_2+a_{3, 1}v_3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
g:\mathbb{R}^2 &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\
x = \alpha_1 u_1+ \alpha_2 u_2 &\longmapsto \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align} be the map that sends each vector $x$ to the unique coefficients in its basis expansion using the basis $(u_1, u_2)$.

Similarly let
\begin{align}
h:\mathbb{R}^3 &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \\
y = \beta_1 v_1+ \beta_2 v_2 + \beta_3 v_3 &\longmapsto \begin{pmatrix} \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \\  \beta_3 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
be the map that sends each vector $y$ to the unique coefficients in the basis expansion of $y$ using the basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$.

Both $g$ and $h$ are invertible linear maps.

Now consider the following diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 \mathbb{R}^2 @>L>> \mathbb{R}^3\\
@VV gV @VhVV\\
\mathbb{R}^2 @>f_M>> \mathbb{R}^3 
\end{CD}
$$
By definition the matrix of $L$ with respect to the given basis is the matrix $M = (M_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$ so that the above diagram commutes, where $f_M$ is the "multiplication with $M$" linear map.

From the diagram it is clear that
$$f_M = h \circ L \circ g^{-1}. \tag{1} $$
Now the question is how to extract the matrix $M$ from this equation. Notice that
$$f_M  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = M   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12} \\ M_{21} & M_{22} \\ M_{31} & M_{32} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  =\begin{pmatrix} M_{11} \\ M_{21} \\ M_{31}\end{pmatrix} ,$$
and similarly
$$f_M  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} M_{12} \\ M_{22}  \\ M_{32}\end{pmatrix} .$$
So all we need to do is to calculate these two values.

Using equation 1 and the form of the inverse of $g$ we obtain:
$$f_M \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=h \circ L \circ g^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = h \circ L (u_1) = ??? \quad \text{(you can calculate this)}
$$
To find $h(L (u_1))$ expand $ L (u_1)$ in the basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ (then you can just read off the coefficients).

Similarly we obtain $f_M \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

In total we arrive at the matrix
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -3 \\
4 & 2 \\
-1 &  2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$
To check for correctness:
We must have $L = h^{-1} \circ f_M \circ g $. Which can be checked for $u_1$ and $u_2$ and is then true for all (by linearity).

Comment: Thank you sooo much @jd27. I finally understand it now.